# Google Assistant - Unable to download credentials after registering device model

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, raspberry-pi4, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to install Google Assistant in my Raspberry Pi4 from my laptop (Windows11) and after completing the steps in https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python#embed I get an error when trying to download the OAuth 2.0 credentials "error  The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again in a few minutes." The error pops up during the device registration step. What could be the problem?

I even tried downloading the OAuth 2.0 in a different browser, different desktop (Windows 10) and in Raspberry Pi itself. Nothing worked.

I even tried downloading the OAuth 2.0 in a different browser, different desktop (Windows 10) and in Raspberry Pi itself. Nothing worked. I deleted the whole project and started again too. I also deleted registered devices and re-registered them. Still nothing worked. Could this be from the pop up on the Google Assistant SDK page : "Conversational Actions will be deprecated on June 13, 2023. For more information, see Conversational Actions sunset."